# how to save CI REST API Logs into file txt

Tags: php, rest, api, continuous-integration

im newbee and confuse how to get value from logs CI Rest API to save into Txt file. The libraries has save into db but i can't get value for creating variable and save into file. Sorry for bad english and help please.

here the code:

```
protected function _log_request($authorized = FALSE)
{
    // Insert the request into the log table
    $is_inserted = $this->rest->db->insert(
        $this->config->item('rest_logs_table'), [
            'uri' => $this->uri->uri_string(),
            'method' => $this->request->method,
            'params' => $this->_args ? ($this->config->item('rest_logs_json_params') === TRUE ? json_encode($this->_args) : serialize($this->_args)) : NULL,
            'api_key' => isset($this->rest->key) ? $this->rest->key : '',
            'ip_address' => $this->input->ip_address(),
            'time' => time(),
            'authorized' => $authorized
        ]);

    //variable for saving value
    $uri        = $this->uri->uri_string();
    $method     = $this->request->method;
    $params     = $this->_args ? ($this->config->item('rest_logs_json_params') === TRUE ? json_encode($this->_args) : serialize($this->_args)) : NULL;
    $api_key    = isset($this->rest->key) ? $this->rest->key : '';
    $ip_address = $this->input->ip_address();
    $time = time();

    //write into file
    $logs = fopen("logs.txt","a");
    fputs($logs, $uri. "\n");
    fputs($logs, $method. "\n");
    fputs($logs, $params. "\n");
    fputs($logs, $api_key. "\n");
    fputs($logs, $ip_address. "\n");
    fputs($logs, $time. "\n");
    fclose($logs);

    // Get the last insert id to update at a later stage of the request
    $this->_insert_id = $this->rest->db->insert_id();       

    return $is_inserted;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
$message="\n\n".str_repeat("=", 100);
$message .= "uri =>".$uri."\n";
$message .= "method=>".$method."\n";
$message .= "params =>".$params."\n";
$message .= "api_key=>".$api_key."\n";
$message .= "ip_address =>".$ip_address."\n";
$message .= "time=>".$time."\n";

$filepath="application/logs/log-".date('Y-m-d').'.txt';
$fp = fopen($filepath, "a")
fwrite($fp, $message);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: the only data stored is $time

Comment: If solution is works then please mark as correct then future user easily find out correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Error Logging Threshold`, Edit `application/config.php`

Enable log

`$config['log_threshold'] = 1;`

You can store debugg message,Information message and error message in to log file

```
0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
2 = Debug Messages
3 = Informational Messages
4 = All Messages
```